# Force open EDGE over Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, html

If you try to open stackoverflow website using Internet Explorer, somehow it closes the tab and opens microsoft edge + browse to stackoverflow website?!

How does stackoverflow accomplish this?

Comment: This is not stackoverflow doing. its being done by Microsoft policies. read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-learnmore-neededge#:~:text=You%20can%20access%20this%20setting,This%20is%20the%20default%20behavior.

Comment: this works for those sites which have sent a request to microsoft that they wont work in IE. but you can set up a javascript redirect to achieve the same. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64555514/15107474

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="microsoft-edge:https://www.stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a>
```

This should open a tab in Edge, but I'm unsure if it'll prioritize Edge over IE.

From what I remember as well, there should be a way to check in JavaScript if the user is using a Windows-related device, and you can then add the 'microsoft-edge:' portion to the href.